# Insert text between text in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using [the following demo](http://jsfiddle.net/828vG/3/), I am trying to highlight some words using a `<span>` tag between some text.

This works correctly for one, however if I try add any more highlights to the paragraph, it either highlights the whole thing, or it clears the previous highlight before adding a new one.

How would I be able to insert multiple highlights to one paragraph?

**Edit** updated the link to try show how i'm adding a second highlight... It doesn't seem to work *exactly the same* as I have

Comment: How are you adding the more highlights?

Comment: Do you want to highlight words, or do you want to give it the position of the words?

Comment: Loop down instead of up if you want to use indices and `innerHTML`

Comment: @Vinoth updated the link to try show.

Comment: @Merguez The data is being retrieved from a DB exactly how the variables are initiated. I need to highlight the words between those indexes.

Comment: @PaulS. Would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @NewAmbition if you're making changes to later parts of a _String_, the earlier parts should all still be located at the same place, so if you start making changes from the end and work back to the beginning, you don't have to worry about positions moving due to the changes you've already made

Comment: I would go for a regex replace where you replace all occuring textToReplace by <span>textToReplace</span>

Comment: @PaulS. The highlights aren't stored or retrieved in order. So some highlights may be set before and/or after the first one.

Comment: @MichielReyers that won't work since he needs a highlight between the indizes. If replacing words instead is an option, try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/828vG/

yeah but you can formulate your SQL query in a way that the replacements will be ordered

Comment: @NewAmbition I've just been looking at your fiddle, it seems as if you've also been mixing `innerHTML` and `innerText`, this is why you're losing previously highlighted items

Comment: @Merguez thats my origional jsfiddle?

Comment: Whoops i'm sorry, check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/828vG/2/

Comment: @Merguez thanks! That seems to work well, however someone might only highlight the 3rd 'e', but then all 'e's will be highlighted.

Comment: @PaulS. Man, I edited it wrong. I've updated the link with the fix, and also upped' the second index so you can see the end result clearly.

Comment: Yes thats a point, was assuming that you just wanted to highlight words in general, when i was writing it. Was just an option for you!

Comment: @Merguez no doubt its definitely an option! Just wish it would work in my environment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about what you want, the only way I can see it working with your requirements is if you use a [*Range*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range). The hardest bit is to convert the index into the real location of your the text you want, which took me a while but I believe this shall work

```
// helper function to walk DOM-tree and find end-points
// basically, converts the index of a character in terms of a HTML element
// into it's offset in a #text Node
function getTextOffset(parent, index) {
    if (parent.nodeType === 3)
        return {'node': parent, 'offset': index};
    var e = parent.childNodes[0], i = index, prev = null;
    while (1) {
        while (e.nodeType !== 3 || e === prev)
            if (e.childNodes && e.childNodes.length)
                e = e.childNodes[0];
            else if (e.nextSibling)
                e = e.nextSibling;
            else {
                while (!e.nextSibling)
                    if (!e.parentNode || e.parentNode === parent)
                        throw RangeError('Index out of range');
                    else
                        e = e.parentNode;
                e = e.nextSibling;
            }
        if (e.data.length < i)
            i -= e.data.length, prev = e;
        else
            return {'node': e, 'offset': i};
    }
}
```

And now all you need is to write a function to create a *Range* and format it..

```
function highlight(node, start, end) {
    var r, o, hi;
    // find text
    r = document.createRange();
    o = getTextOffset(node, start); // find start point
    r.setStart(o.node, o.offset);   // set start in range
    o = getTextOffset(node, end);   // find end point
    r.setEnd(o.node, o.offset);     // set end in range
    // now format
    hi = document.createElement('span');
    hi.style.background = 'yellow';
    hi.appendChild(r.extractContents());
    r.insertNode(hi);
    // cleanup
    r.detach();
}

highlight(containerEl, 3, 5); // invoke
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WUY6C/)

Comment: This is... Beautiful.

Comment: Any chance you could get this working in IE8? I have tried something along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/7u8Bc/, but it still wont work out correctly... PS: JSBin doesnt seem to work in IE8

Comment: Tested in IE11 emulating IE8. IE8 does not support _Range_, so `document.createRange; // undefined in IE8-`. You might be able to use the _Rangy_ library to make it work.

Comment: We have Rangy, was just hoping to be as pureJS as possible :) Thanks for the update though!